# Low-latency screenshot from Android emulator

Tags: screenshots

I'd like to grab the screen 10 times a second to feed it into a computer vision model.

Running `screencap` in a loop in adb shell is too slow.

Other answers have suggested reading from `/dev/graphics/fb0`, but my emulator does not have this file.

Ideas for how to do this?

Comment: As it is an emulator wouldn't it be simpler to directly capture the screen on host side?

Comment: Yeah, that could work. Ideally I'd like something I can run both on an emulated device and on a real device connected through USB.

Comment: But your title clearly limits the question to emulators. For real devices check out `scrcpy`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [screenrecord not working in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933605/screenrecord-not-working-in-emulator)